# why spark sort is slower than scala original sort method

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark

I heard many people says that Spark art good at sorting and distributed computing. Currently, out team do some research on spark and scala. We are going to implement an sorting service on spark. Right now, I have setup the spark cluster, and try to run and sorting example on spark cluster, but the cost time of sorting seems to long. Here is my code.

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import scala.util.Random

/**
 * Created by  on 1/1/15.
 */
object AdvancedSort {
  /**
   * bin/spark-submit --master spark://master:7077 --executor-memory 1024M --class com.my.sortedspark.AdvancedSort lib/sortedspark.jar 100000 3
   * @param args
   */
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sampleSize = if (args.length > 0) args(0).toInt else 100000
    val slice = if (args.length > 1) args(1).toInt else 3

    sort(sampleSize, slice)
  }

  def sort(listSize: Int, slice: Int): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(getClass.getName)
    val spark = new SparkContext(conf)
    val step1 = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val data = genRandom(listSize)
    val step2 = System.currentTimeMillis()
    println(">>>>>>>>>> genRandom : " + (step2 - step1))

    val distData = spark.parallelize(data, slice)
    val step3 = System.currentTimeMillis()
    println(">>>>>>>>>> parallelize : " + (step3 - step2))

    val result = distData.sortBy(x => x, true).collect
    val step4 = System.currentTimeMillis()
    println(">>>>>>>>>> sortBy and collect: " + (step4 - step3))
    println(">>>>>>>>>> total time : " + (step4 - step1))

    printlnArray(result, 0, 10)

    spark.stop()
  }

  /**
   * generate random number
   * @return
   */
  def genRandom(listSize: Int): List[Int] = {
    val range = 100000
    var listBuffer = new ListBuffer[Int]
    val random = new Random()
    for (i <- 1 to listSize) listBuffer += random.nextInt(range)
    listBuffer.toList
  }

  def printlnList(list: List[Int], start: Int, offset: Int) {
    for (i <- start until start + offset) println(">>>>>>>>> list : " + i + " | " + list(i))
  }

  def printlnArray(list: Array[Int], start: Int, offset: Int) {
    for (i <- start until start + offset) println(">>>>>>>>> list : " + i + " | " + list(i))
  }
}
```

After deploy the above code into spark cluster, I run the following command under Master's Spark Home:

```
bin/spark-submit --master spark://master:7077 --executor-memory 1024M --class com.my.sortedspark.AdvancedSort lib/sortedspark.jar 100000 3
```

The following is cost time which I got finally.

```
>>>>>>>>>> genRandom : 86
>>>>>>>>>> parallelize : 53
>>>>>>>>>> sortBy and collect: 6756
```

This looks strange, because if I run 100000 random data of Int via scala's sorted method on my local machine, the cost time is quicker the spark's.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import scala.util.Random

/**
 * Created by  on 1/5/15.
 */
object ScalaSort {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val list = genRandom(1000000)
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val result = list.sorted
    val end = System.currentTimeMillis()
    println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> cost time : " + (end - start))
  }

  /**
   * generate random number
   * @return
   */
  def genRandom(listSize: Int): List[Int] = {
    val range = 100000
    var listBuffer = new ListBuffer[Int]
    val random = new Random()
    for (i <- 1 to listSize) listBuffer += random.nextInt(range)
    listBuffer.toList
  }
}
```

cost time of scala's sorted method on local machine

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> cost time : 169
```

In my opinion, the following factors costume spark's sorting time:

1. data transfor between Master and Worker
2. sorting on Worker is quick, by merge may be slow.

Does any master of spark know why this happen?

Comment: 100000 elements is tiny. A in-memory sort will beat the parallel version because of the overheads, as you say. Try a properly big array.

Comment: Hi Paul, try a bigger array will show the advantage of spark. But I have other question, is it possible to tuning the cost time into 100ms?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "tuning the cost time". Spark is meant for big problems. If you don't have a big problem, don't use Spark, or don't be surprised when it's not faster?

Comment: Chan you results are consistent and not surprising given what you are trying to do. I agree with @Paul - the total cost of setting up the infrastructure for Spark is not worth it if your data size fits in memory of a single node for something like sorting (which is the case here). You will see the benefits only when you can amortize the cost of setup and distribution.

Comment: Hi Paul&Soumya, 100000 element is tiny, but this is only for test purpose. Our team's final purpose is to provide an sorting service, and the input data cloud be multi-dimension, do you think is possible to reduce the sorting cost time. If this is not possible, then our team will try other solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to measure the big array and see how the time goes. The overhead will be (relatively) constant and you should see speed up for large arrays.

Comment: Of course, you're free to choose whatever product you like, but I suggest you first check out the winner here: http://sortbenchmark.org/ If you need only to sort, maybe you can even go with specialized product, like Triton. The fact that Spark is equally fast (as a narrowly specialized Triton) is only a testament to how incredible Spark really is.

Answer (score 1):

Spark is made for BigData. 
When You insert tiny numbers to it, it acts slower because distribution over all cores/cluster takes more time than it'd take to sort it normally. 
Try to use bigger data or instead of Spark use ParCollections in Scala :

```
collection.par.<any code here>
```